# Using Azure AD MFA with MIM and on-premise apps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identity, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to use MFA for on-premise APPS that are secured by AD and ADFS. We are uing MIM to provision accounts automatically to AD. However all accounts will not be synchronized to Azure AD. I have read following article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/pam/use-azure-mfa-for-activation

Does it mean you can use Azure AD MFA withing MIM for on-premise Apps which are secured by ADFS? does it go to Azure AD to challenge the user for MFA? what about if the account exist only in AD not Azure AD?

Appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

The article you cited above is only applicable to the use of Azure AD MFA within MIM for the privileged access management scenario, rather than for MFA for use within applications.  I would recommend synchronizing accounts to Azure AD, and using conditional access and the application proxy where applicable.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-whichversion for more info on the options for applications.